# How do I create a table that counts the number of times the same text occurs in a field in SQLite?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table that has a text column.  I can generate a table that can separate the number of distinct rows like this:

```sql
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS msgs;
CREATE TABLE msgs (
    Msg TEXT
);
INSERT INTO msgs(Msg) SELECT DISTINCT Message FROM Log;
```

But I'd like to add a column into `msgs` that states how many times that `Msg` actually occurred in the `Log` table.  I tried reading [SQLite COUNT](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-count-function/) page, but I'm not clear as how I'd put that into the `INSERT INTO` statement.  I'm new to more advanced (intermediate?) stuff in SQL, so I'm finding it hard to wrap my head around it.  Any ideas as how I'd do this?  Any reference material that would help me figure this out would also be appreciated.

Comment: 1) Create a view instead of a table, will always be up-to-date.

Comment: 2) Do a GROUP BY.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of DISTINCT, you should use [`GROUP BY`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp) and an aggregated function, in this case, [`COUNT()`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_count_avg_sum.asp)

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS msgs;
CREATE TABLE msgs (
    Msg TEXT
    Msg_count int
);
    INSERT INTO msgs(Msg, msg_count)
    SELECT Message, count(Message) as msg_count FROM Log
    
    group by Message;
```

Comment: I see that it works, but I don't understand why it works.  I think I'm having trouble understanding the SQL grammer.

Comment: @Adrian follow the links. You need to practice with the `group by` and aggregated functions.

Answer (score 1):

You can aggregate the data set using `GROUP BY`. For example:

```
CREATE TABLE msgs (
    Msg TEXT,
    cnt int    
);

INSERT INTO msgs(Msg, cnt) 
SELECT Message, count(*) 
FROM Log 
GROUP BY Msg;
```